# how can i share a image with comment to line app?

Tags: android

i can share a image by:

```
String lineString = "line://msg/image/" + localFileName;
Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(lineString, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

but how to add a comment to shared image? please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The comment you want to share");
```